# Using pip 10.0.1 to install modules

Tags: pip, pycharm

lately using 9.0.1,  I have been using Project Interpreter to import modules for my files. I opened up a new project in PyCharm today to try and test 10.0.1. Using the Pip version of 10.0.1, I couldn't install packages into my file.

The command output was :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2017.3.3\helpers\packaging_tool.py", line 192, in main
    retcode = do_install(pkgs)
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2017.3.3\helpers\packaging_tool.py", line 109, in do_install
    return pip.main(['install'] + pkgs)
AttributeError: module 'pip' has no attribute 'main'
```

I googled this and it said that installing modules through pip was now unsupported, especially for

pip._internal.main

After looking at this site : `https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/user_guide/#using-pip-from-your-program` for a while, it says to use :

```
subprocess.check_call([sys.executable, '-m', 'pip', 'install', 'my_package'])
```

I tried executing it and command prompt said that subprocess.check_call is not an internal or external file.

i also tried executing the commands through Command Prompt and downgrading my pip to 9.0.1 but none of this worked. When I changed Pip to 9.0.1 in Command Prompt, it had no effect on PyCharm.

Can anyone help with trying to import modules into PyCharm because I am currently trying to make a webcrawler using modules beautifulsoup4 and it is not letting me import it.